# mod_rewrite redirect all to https except one file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i use this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

to redirect all request to HTTPS and that is ok.

Now I want same thing except one file index810.php

when i write like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ index810.php
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

i get too many redirects, any suggestions.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A** solution is to use a non rewriting rule:

```
# do nothing for /index810.php
RewriteRule ^index810\.php$ - [L]
# else ...
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Your pattern was wrong:

- there is a space between ^ and index810.php
- %{REQUEST_URI} is all the HTTP path (ie, if at document root, it would be `=/index810.php`)

Comment: Thank you very much julp i modify it a little to make it more general work great!

    RewriteRule ^.*index810\.php$ - [L]

Comment: To make it work for /index810.php, instead of `^index810\.php$`, I think you should use `^/index810\.php$`

Comment: @lucaferrario: in a directory context (ie in a .htaccess or a `<Directory>` block) Apache removes the part of the path of the URL which maps to the directory for RewriteRule. [The documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) says: "[...] The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, **a pattern with `^/` never matches in per-directory context**. [...]". Your remark only applies if RewriteRule is not in a directory context (rules directly in a VirtualHost for example).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. This did however:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index810\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```