# mod rewrite redirect all to https except one file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect all my pages so they use the HTTPS protocol except one path. I did find the following page ( [mod_rewrite redirect all to https except one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141216/mod-rewrite-redirect-all-to-https-except-one-file) ), but the solution provided there didn't work for me. I have also tried other solutions, all to no avail.

Here is my current code:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# do nothing for my-awesome-path.php
RewriteRule ^keg-collars-studio\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1\.php [QSA,L]
```

I have edited my post with the exact content and path. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The path is mysite.com/my-awesome-path.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# Turn SSL off everything but payments
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/keg-collars-studio\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine now. I have removed the space between the ^ and https on this line: RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]